# update selection field using xml-rpc

Tags: updates, odoo, xmlrpclib

i want to ask how can i change state on my odoo from 'confirmed' to 'In progress' using python
i want code like this:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mrp.production', 'write', [[ids], {'state': "In Progress"}])
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to provide value of state field which has stored in database.

Try with following code:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mrp.production', 'write', [ids], {'state': 'progress'})
```

Comment: thnx you for your help, but got this error:  in call_kw_multi\nTypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument \'state\'\n'>